# iOS crash - no leaks, NSZombie enabled and doesn't breaking on exceptions

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, crash, avplayer

I am writing an iPad app which uses an AVPlayer to display a video.  There's buttons to jump to various parts of the video, and when the user rotates the device, I change the size of the view which holds the AVPlayer layer.

My problem is that after a certain amount of device orientation changes and jumps around the video, the app crashes.

I have NSZombie enabled - this doesn't break.
I have a breakpoint enabled in my code to catch exceptions - this doesn't break.
I have run instruments and the code isn't leaking.

Allocations simply shows the "Overall Bytes" growing and growing with every action until it hits 14 meg and the pad crashes.

I feel like I have no way of getting to the bottom of this.  Am I missing some trick to solving this?  Does AVPlayer need some special treatment when being released?

ANY HELP, MUCH APPRECIATED.

Comment: What does the console tell you?

Comment: Yeah, specifically, does it mention logging a "LowMemory" log file?

Comment: The only message in the console other some TestFlight checkpoints is "Received memory warning." about 250 milliseconds before the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Use instruments to check your Allocations. I recently had a very similar problem where there were no memory leaks but my Overall Bytes kept growing every time I launched a particular ViewController (and it would eventually crash).

It turned out that the ViewController itself was a strong reference as a delegate to another class (oops) and each time I dismissed the ViewController that other class still had a reference to it. Therefore each time I launched and dismissed this ViewController I would create another instance of it that would never die (and never leak).

Your exact problem may be different but you should be able to see the reason for your Overall Bytes growing by checking out your Allocations.

Comment: Thanks SteveB.  The problem is occuring within a single ViewController, and allocations just has thousands of small allocations and nothing very big.  I'll analyse the allocations list more thoroughly to see if I can spot a pattern.  Thanks so much.